# Как сделать, чтобы placeholder (или label?) в input при фокусе смещался вверх и уменьшался?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, input, placeholder

Хочется как-то средствами CSS обойтись

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Пример

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form {
  padding: 15px;
}

.form-item {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}

.form-input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

.form-label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 40px;
  transition: .3s;
}

.form-input:focus~.form-label,
.form-input:not(:focus):valid~.form-label {
  top: -10px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <div class="form-item">
    <input type="text" class="form-input" required>
    <label class="form-label">Text</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item">
    <input type="text" class="form-input" required>
    <label class="form-label">Text 2</label>
  </div>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Вроде, все основные стили ввёл, но работает наоборот. Когда поле пустое, label всё время держится наверху. Когда я поле заполню и фокус уберу, то label становится по умолчанию, наползает на текст. Может это из-за bootstrap стилей?

Comment: вполне возможно, инспектором попробуйте на конфликт

Comment: Я выяснил, что это из-за :valid. Почему-то он работает как :invalid. А с последним соответственно всё заработало как надо. Но что-то понять не могу почему так.

Comment: Вариант с bootstrap - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/o1rh7gf6/ Все работает

Comment: Убрал просто required. Раньше не пользовался никогда :valid )